# Something is caching my web page

Tags: networking, cache

I have a page that is marked do not cache. When I hit Ctrl-F5 on my browser, I git the current version and an older version, each about %50 of the time. Something is caching it somewhere.

We have cleared the cache on our web servers and are still getting a cached copy.

dig only returns one IP address for the address so it's not doing round-robin DNS, which was the first thing I thought of since it's %50 of the time.

I have done searches on caching and all hits are about browser caches, which this is not the problem. I remember that some switches cache web pages and I'm thinking this is what's going on, but how do I track it down?

Comment: Eliminate possibilities. Does it happen from other systems? With other browsers on the same system? With the same browser on a different system? Without a browser at all? (Try curl, wget or even telnet.)

Comment: ... and if @MichaelKjörling's measures don't find the problem, then you may have to resort to tracing the traffic with [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/).